# Can some one help me with deleting records from my Db Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have tried this code below saw it on a trend but I dont know why its not working

```
Posts.destroy({ where: { createdAt: { isAfter: "2016-09-11" } } })
```

I want to destroy posts that are after 24hrs so I modified the above to

```
Posts.destroy({ where: { createdAt: { isAfter: new Date() } } })
```

I want to destroy all post after today
Then I fetch to see the post that are left but I am still seeing the existing post

Answer (score 2):

isAfter seems to be a Validator. [Validators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#validations)

You are maybe looking for the $gt operator. [Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators)

Something like:

```
createdAt: {
  $gt: new Date()
}
```

Comment: So true I just found it out yes ur correct I also found this was a known issue on the web glad that the solution is here.